# Multi language support for website

Tags: c#, asp.net, multilingual

I am building a website using Asp.net with C# and back end support is SQL server.How to add multilingual support to it?Like in google or facebook there are various link button for various languages?I want to implement the same thing.Please help.Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Google and Facebook employ the help of translators to produce their various language features. This is a process called localization is often a very complicated and difficult process. If you are working by yourself, I would be wary of actually doing your own localization unless you are a native speaker or are fluent in the languages you want to translate your pages to.

If you would like users from around the world to be able to use your page in their native language, you may consider placing a link on your site that uses Google Translator or another translation service to convert your page text for you. It is not a perfect solution, but may help you get up and running.

If this doesn't suit your needs, you will need to do the localization yourself. I'm no expert on the process, but there is a simple pattern you can follow. Take blocks of text on your website and translate them into the different languages you want to support, and depending on which language the user specifies in their preferences, pick that block of text that matches that language.

This [Wikipedia Article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internationalization_and_localization) may help you better understand the processes and the complications that are involved.

This [MSDN Article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c6zyy3s9.aspx) discusses best practices and tips for doing localization in ASP.net.

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to define somewhere all text and choose on a request the language you want to use.

Translating and maintaining translated texts is a non trivial task, maybe [String | Create a multi-language website or app](http://mygengo.com/string/about) will help you a lot.